# How to enable UPnP/NAT-PMP in a setup with cascaded routers

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a network setup with two cascaded routers (no double-NAT) and I want to enable UPnP/NAT-PMP on all subnets.

Setup:

```
<Internet>--<Router 1>+--<Router 2>+--<Subnet 1>--<Laptop etc.>
                      |            +--<Subnet 2>--<IOT devices>
                      +--<IPTV Device>
```

- Router 1 is connected to my ISP. It gets the public IP (IPv4 + IPv6) and does NAT into a private  IP subnet (e.g. 192.168.10.0/24).
- Router 2 is connected to router 1, adds additional subnets (e.g. 192.168.200.0/24 + 192.168.300.0/24) and routes between them – no NAT.

I want to enable port forwarding via UPnP/NAT-PMP for devices connected to router 2. I'm not sure if that's possible at all and how to do it.

Router 1 is a FritzBox running its own stack incl. UPnP capabilities. These are enabled.
Router 2 is a Unifi USG running miniupnpd.

**My question is:** Does the UPnP protocol forward port-forwarding requests across subnets? Is there any way to enable this? Do I need to add a reflector service like Avahi but for UPnP?

Comment: Interesting question, I believe it uses a multicast address for discovery. the upnp app would need to be listening to the multicast address. So you would probably need a proxy to forward it?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart So basically disabling the miniupnpd on the USG and adding something like PIMD there could work?